# formato de tabla dinámica usando openXML - c#

Tags: c#, openxml

Buen día, estoy trabajando con openXML creando una tabla dinámica. lleno el XML con información, y creo una tabla con la información recién ingresada.
el código que genera la tabla dinámica es la siguiente

```
var pt = res.PivotTables.Add("PivotTable", res.Cell(1, 1), table.AsRange()); //res es una hoja de excel llamada "Resumen", tabla es la hoja donde saco la información para la tabla dinámica
            //se agregan los registros que se van a agregar
            pt.RowLabels.Add("Sucursal");
            pt.RowLabels.Add("C. proveedor");
            pt.RowLabels.Add("Proveedor");
            pt.Values.Add("Total");
            res.Column("D").Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$###,###,###.00";
            return workbook.Deliver("Reporte por proveedores.xlsx");
```

El código funciona y genera la tabla pivote, pero no me da el formato deseado, mi sistema genera el reporte de la siguiente manera:

```
campo1       campo2            campo3

datoColumna1
             datoColumna2
                              datoColumna3
```

la idea es que la tabla pivote genere los datos en la misma columna, algo así:

```
campo1       campo2            campo3
datoColumna1 datoColumna2      datoColumna3
```

intenté con estos parámetros pero no afectan a los rows en sí:

```
pt.AutofitColumns = true;
pt.PreserveCellFormatting = true;
pt.SetAutofitColumns(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer, se tiene que aplicar el estilo clásico a la tabla dinámica para que imprima todo en la misma fila. para hacer esto, tienes que poner la siguiente línea:

```
pt.ClassicPivotTableLayout = true;
```

donde "pt" es la variable que usamos para generar la tabla dinámica.